# How can I test and train multiple data sets in the form of two lists?

Tags: r, list, testing, cross-validation, training-data

I would like to create a function to train and test 10 separate data sets, in two lists.  Here are the lists:

```
blend_30_d<-list(desktop_30_1, desktop_30_2, desktop_30_3, desktop_30_4, desktop_30_5, desktop_30_6, desktop_30_7, desktop_30_8, desktop_30_9, desktop_30_10)

blend_30_td<-list(desktop_30_t1, desktop_30_t2, desktop_30_t3, desktop_30_t4, desktop_30_t5, desktop_30_t6, desktop_30_t7, desktop_30_t8, desktop_30_t9, desktop_30_t10)
```

The names of each individual dataset are:

[1] "date"                "Wkday"               "Imps"                "Clicks"              "Total_Cost"          "Units"
 [7] "January"             "February"            "March"               "April"               "May"                 "June"
[13] "July"                "August"              "September"           "October"             "November"            "December"
[19] "Monday"              "Tuesday"             "Wednesday"           "Thursday"            "Friday"              "Saturday"
[25] "Sunday"              "Vday"                "Tgiving"             "Xmas"                "XmasE"               "NYE"
[31] "NYD"                 "July4"               "Labor"               "Memorial"            "Mob_App_Launch"      "Auto_Approve_Launch"

I've built the following function- I want blend_30_d[1] to get tested against blend_30_td[1].

```
d_cost <- function(train, test){
    ####Run regression on training
    q<-lm(Total_Cost ~ . -date - Wkday - Imps - Clicks + poly(date, 2), data=train)
    ####Predict values into test set
    test_cost_d <- predict.lm(q, x=test)
    ####Calculate R^2 between predicted vs. actual values
    z<-(cor(test_cost_d, test$Total_Cost))^2
}

d_cost(blend_30_d, blend_30_td)
```

I'm receiving the following error: 
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  duplicated name 'date' in data frame using '.'

I'm not sure that this is the correct approach with two lists...any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `d_cost` function is built to take two data frames, one for testing and one for training. You're trying to call it by passing it two lists of data frames. You've built your function for one pair of data frames at a time, so you need to give it one pair, not 2 lists of pairs. Try something like this:

```
z = rep(NA, length(blend_30_d)
for (i in seq_along(blend_30_d) {
    z[i] = d_cost(blend_30_d[[i]], blend_30_td[[i]])
}
```

Comment: this works well for the 10 sets- unfortunately, the R^2 values (z) are still off.  Now I think my q values might need to loop as well?

Comment: @user2573355 It sounds like you're having trouble because you're trying to do everything all at once. Take things one step at a time. Don't start with 10 data frames. Start with a single train/test pair, get that how you want it, and then build from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add a loop:

```
for(i in 1:10){
    d_cost(train[[i]], test[[i]])
}
```